# Creating a mesh map with river cross-profiles

Tags: mesh, map

I am trying to create a type of 3D mesh map using multiple cross profiles/cross-sections of a river. I have the longitude, latitude, and elevation imported, with two examples shown below:

```
XS1={{154301., 814587., 52.602}, {154301., 814587., 52.576}, {154300., 
  814587., 52.414}, {154300., 814587., 52.22}, {154299., 814587., 
  51.726}, {154298., 814587., 51.713}, {154298., 814587., 
  51.533}, {154297., 814587., 51.28}, {154297., 814587., 
  51.}, {154296., 814587., 50.827}, {154296., 814587., 
  50.608}, {154295., 814587., 50.538}, {154295., 814587., 
  50.507}, {154294., 814587., 50.556}, {154293., 814588., 
  50.476}, {154293., 814588., 50.47}, {154292., 814588., 
  50.327}, {154292., 814588., 50.27}, {154291., 814588., 
  50.163}, {154291., 814588., 50.188}, {154290., 814588., 
  50.251}, {154290., 814588., 50.334}, {154289., 814588., 
  50.39}, {154289., 814588., 50.465}, {154288., 814588., 
  50.473}, {154288., 814588., 50.466}, {154287., 814588., 
  50.492}, {154286., 814588., 50.495}, {154286., 814588., 
  50.484}, {154285., 814588., 50.457}, {154285., 814588., 
  50.413}, {154284., 814588., 50.397}, {154284., 814588., 
  50.435}, {154283., 814588., 50.413}, {154283., 814588., 
  50.395}, {154282., 814588., 50.392}, {154282., 814588., 
  50.403}, {154281., 814588., 50.456}, {154281., 814588., 
  50.472}, {154280., 814589., 50.445}, {154280., 814589., 
  50.537}, {154279., 814589., 50.67}, {154279., 814589., 
  50.781}, {154278., 814589., 51.291}, {154278., 814589., 
  51.341}, {154277., 814589., 51.679}, {154277., 814589., 51.925}}
```

```
XS2={{154298., 814561., 52.584}, {154297., 814561., 52.129}, {154297., 
  814561., 51.935}, {154296., 814561., 51.785}, {154295., 814561., 
  51.765}, {154295., 814561., 51.703}, {154294., 814561., 
  51.45}, {154294., 814561., 51.458}, {154293., 814561., 
  50.931}, {154292., 814561., 50.638}, {154292., 814561., 
  50.506}, {154291., 814561., 49.892}, {154290., 814561., 
  49.873}, {154290., 814561., 49.792}, {154289., 814561., 
  49.792}, {154289., 814561., 49.887}, {154288., 814561., 
  49.912}, {154288., 814561., 49.967}, {154287., 814561., 
  49.971}, {154287., 814561., 50.086}, {154286., 814561., 
  50.108}, {154285., 814561., 50.166}, {154285., 814561., 
  50.204}, {154284., 814561., 50.211}, {154284., 814561., 
  50.281}, {154283., 814561., 50.303}, {154283., 814561., 
  50.306}, {154282., 814561., 50.349}, {154282., 814561., 
  50.389}, {154281., 814561., 50.437}, {154281., 814561., 
  50.424}, {154280., 814561., 50.377}, {154280., 814560., 
  50.381}, {154279., 814560., 50.345}, {154279., 814560., 
  50.289}, {154277., 814560., 50.87}, {154276., 814560., 
  51.061}, {154276., 814560., 51.078}, {154276., 814560., 
  51.351}, {154275., 814560., 51.574}, {154275., 814560., 51.866}}
```

I would have more cross-sections in my actual data but I use two here for simplicity.
I have tried using a variety of 3D plotting methods but am not well-versed in mathematic or coding in general so have struggled figuring out how to do this.

In my head I am trying to get something like the below photograph (colors not relevant), only using my data to show the bed of a river using several of my cross-sections.

[image]

Any guidance on methods to use or a code that could get me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you are looking for [**`ListContourPlot3D`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot3D.html)?

Comment: How about `ListPlot3D[XS1, PlotRange -> All]`?

Comment: Have you seen the section [meshes from elevation data](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#329657088)

Comment: These solutions are very close to what I am wanting but iI can't seem to get them to work with the data I have. I'm not sure if it is my lack of understanding on how these functions work exactly or because of my data itself. The "meshes from elevation data" comment is visually how i would like my data but I again can't figure out how exactly to apply it to my data (provided above)